# Thermodynamics of binary symmetric channels

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, quantum-information, entropy, specific-reference

I am reading this very interesting paper:
http://m.iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/41/40/402002/pdf/1751-8121_41_40_402002.pdf about thermodynamics of channels in information theory.

More generally, establishing a dictionary between information theory and thermodynamics is an old idea, but it seems to me that we only transpose state parameters (entropy, energy, temperature) and not transformations (adiabatic, isothermic).

For instance, mutual information between input and output is related in this paper to internal energy. Suppose we are trying to simulate the BSC using other channels. We would quantify the efficiency of this simulation by looking at the mutual information. The channels having exactly the same mutual information as BSC are indistinguishable from BSC. The dictionary with thermodynamics would lead us to think that we are performing an adiabatic transform in the space of channels. However I can find no rigorous formulation for this intuition, nor any paper on the possible interpretations of thermodynamic transforms for information theory channels.

Comment: Minor point concerning retagging: I would say that the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply here cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).